# Как получить View элемента Preference?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-shared-preferences, android-preferences

Есть `PreferenceFragment`, в котором разворачиваются строки преференсов:

```
@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String s) {
    PreferenceManager manager = getPreferenceManager();
    manager.setSharedPreferencesName("my_preferences");
    manager.setSharedPreferencesMode(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.main_preferences);
    //blah-blah
    final Preference myPref = findPreference(getString(R.string.my_pref));
    myPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener((Preference preference) -> {
            //blah-blah
            return true;
        });
}
```

В реале, [если заглянуть под капот](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-camerax-release/preference/preference/src/main/java/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.java) понятно, что преференсы разворачиваются в виде списка `RecyclerView`.

**Внимание вопрос:** как получить ссылку на `View` поверх которого получен `Preference myPref`?

Comment: перегружать класс и ловить в onBindView

Comment: Проблема в том, что в классе `PreferenceFragment` `onBindView()` недоступен

Comment: так вам нужен View для Preference - вот его и перегружайте

Comment: Вы видимо не понимаете о чем говорите. Объект класса `Preference` мне возвращает система при вызове `findPreference()` - каким образом здесь поможет перегрузка `Preference`?

Comment: а хамить зачем? Я понимаю о чем говорю и у меня есть опыт разработки в данном вопросе, собственно поэтому и влез, но уже пожалел. Вы создаете свой Custom Preference и вставляете ЕГО в фрагмент, далее его ищите и используете.

Comment: В упор не вижу хамства... просто надо писать более понятно, а то непонятно о чем вы пишете.